# Call C# method with two types of list as parameters

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new with C# and I would like to simplify my code. I would like to call a C# method which contains parameters. One of these parameters is a list, but I have an issue with that.

This is my code :

```
if (condition)
   {
        List<DonneesFinancieresGn> donneeFinanciereCourante = something;
        GestionAbsenceDonneesFinancieres(donneeFinanciereCourante);
   }
else
   {
        List<DonneesFinancieresArchive> donneeFinanciereArchive = something;
        GestionAbsenceDonneesFinancieres(donneeFinanciereArchive);                    
   }
```

And the called method :

```
public void GestionAbsenceDonneesFinancieres(var donneeFinanciereList)
    {
        if (donneeFinanciereList != null && donneeFinanciereList.Any())
           {
             ...
           }
    }
```

But I have an issue, because `donneeFinanciereCourante` as the type `List<DonneesFinancieresGn>` and `donneeFinanciereArchive` as the type `List<DonneesFinancieresArchive>`.

My question is : Which kind of type I could use in my method `GestionAbsenceDonneesFinancieres()` for the parameter `donneeFinanciereList` in order to take into account both types ?

**EDIT**

It could work if I write something like this ?

```
public void GestionAbsenceDonneesFinancieres<T>(List<T> donneeFinanciereList)
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mre]? It's unclear what the relation Let `DonneesFinancieresGn` and `DonneesFinancieresArchive` is. If you want to treat them the same, let them inherit the same base class or implement the same interface, and make your parameter a collection of that type (e.g. `IList<IDonneesFinancieres>`).

Comment: As for your edit, yes, that could work, but you couldn't do anything meaningful with the list elements, as your compiler doesn't know what members `T` has - you'll then need to constrain it to the interface or base class from my comment above.

Comment: I would like to apply the same treatment to both lists. But sometimes the if condition is succeed, sometimes no. I edited my question with maybe a result which could work ?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok I reduced my question with minimal example. I don't know How I can do something like this because I'm a beginner. But I will search documentation about your idea.

Comment: Pb résolut pour ton select many? voila si j'ai bien compris. Mais honnêtement c'était pas claire et le screen shoot était assez peu utile ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/17eQJ4. Tu pourra me faire un petit accusé de lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do has several ways of being solved, I will explain the pros and cons of them depending on how your types relate to one another.

1- You can have 2 methods that will only differ in the type of the list (since your Types' names are too long I will use `A` and `B` for brevity and `Method` for the method name, you should be able to replace without issues):

```cs
public void Method(List<A> input) 
{
    // your code for A specific list
}

public void Method(List<B> input) 
{
    // your code for B specific list
}
```

PROS: very simple design, will always work regardless of how your types relate to each other, this is the way to go if you have specific behavior depending on the types
CONS: You can have a lot of duplicate code this way

2- Using generics as you suggested:

```cs
public void Method<T>(List<T> input)
{
    // your code
}
```

PROS: your code will run :-p
CONS: you will not know what it inside the list at compile-time, this kind of methods is useful when you only need to perform operations on the lists, and the objects inside them have no real importance to you

If your types have a common ancestor (or one directly inherits from the other) and you could use that ancestor (or the base type) then you could constraint your generic parameter so you can use that ancestor in your code, something like this:

```cs
public class Ancestor
{
    public int Age {get; set; }
}

public class A: Ancestor
{
    public int Count {get; set;}
}

public class B: Ancestor
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
/// ....

public void Method<T>(List<T> input) where T: Ancestor
{
    // now you can do
    input[0].Age; // and the compiler will be happy

    // you cannot do
    input[0].Count;
    input[0].Data;
   
    // even if you are actually working with List<A> or List<B>
}
```

this will fall short if you need to use specific data from each type, in which case then the first solution is the one to go with

If your types don't have a common ancestor, then maybe you should consider creating an interface with all the common properties and methods you will be using and have them both inherit from that interface then your method can be like this:

```cs
public void Method<T>(List<T> input) where T: IMyInterface
```

PROS: you should have minimal code duplication like this
CONS: your method can get a little inconsistent since it can be called like this:

```cs
var myList = new List<IMyInterface> { new A(), new B() };
Method(myList);
```

or, in the case of common inheritor:

```cs
var myList = new List<Ancestor> { new A(), new B() };
Method(myList);
```

which you might not want. Also, if you need specific data on your types, again, 1 is the one to go with

Another idea is to create a class to hold all the data you need and have it being initialized from both `A` and `B` so it knows what data to extract and then use that in your method:

```cs
public class CommonDataObject
{
    public CommonDataObject(A input){...}
    public CommonDataObject(B input){...}
}

public void Method(List<CommonDataObject> input){...}

// and to call your method given a list of A or B
var myList = myListOfAorB.Select(x => new CommonDataObject(x));
Method(myList);
```

PROS: you will avoid code duplication and side effects on the original list, although since your method is void, those side effects seem to be what you are aiming for
CONS: this takes a bit more work to do and might not be possible at all if `Method` behaves too differently depending on the types, in which case then maybe the first solution would be best

Answer (score -1):

It has to the type returned in

```
DonneesFinancieresRepository.LireDonneesFinancieresBase(idArchive)
```

Comment: They want to call that method with two different `List<T>` types.